# How to get the position of a dynamically added view relative to its parent

Tags: android, layout, view, position, coordinate

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageParams= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200,200);
ImageView mImageView=new ImageView(this);
mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
viewParent.addView(mImageView, imageParams);
```

Under my touch event, i log getX, getLeft and leftMargin of my view.

```
18835-18835/com.android.test E/﹕ getX: 260.49933 getLeft: 0.0 leftMargin: 0.0
```

Why getLeft and leftMargin return 0? How can i get the view's position relative to its parent?

**EDIT**

XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.now.stickit.EditNoteActivity"
    android:id="@+id/edit_note_layout">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/view_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/canvas_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>

   <LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/primary">

   <ImageButton
       android:id="@+id/addText"
       android:layout_width="45dp"
       android:layout_height="45dp"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add_text"
       android:background="#00000000"/>

   <ImageButton
       android:id="@+id/draw"
       android:layout_width="45dp"
       android:layout_height="45dp"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_action_draw"
       android:background="#00000000"/>

   <ImageButton
       android:id="@+id/erase"
       android:layout_width="45dp"
       android:layout_height="45dp"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_action_erase"
       android:background="#00000000"/>

   <ImageButton
       android:id="@+id/addImage"
       android:layout_width="45dp"
       android:layout_height="45dp"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add_image"
       android:background="#00000000"/>

   <ImageButton
       android:id="@+id/undo"
       android:layout_width="45dp"
       android:layout_height="45dp"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_action_undo"
       android:background="#00000000"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I added an imageview programmatically into the relative layout. Then I am able to drag and drop the image any where inside the view

[image]

```
06-16 02:34:45.858    2721-2721/com.android.test E/﹕ getX: 206.57422getLeft: 0.0leftMargin: 0.0
```

[image]

```
06-16 02:43:28.566    2721-2721/com.now.stickit E/﹕ getX: 225.54785getLeft: 0.0leftMargin: 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to provide image for your question for visualization.

Quoting the documentation:

> getLeft ()
>
> Left position of this view relative to its parent.

So you are adding your view inside RelativeLayout and it goes to top, left corner. It is normal behavior and `getLeft()` and `getLeftMargin()` will return 0.

> How can i get the view's position relative to its parent?

So now your are getting your view position relative to it's parent. Maybe your forget to add some rules on your `RelativeLayout.Params`?

Comment: I have edited my post, added some screen shots. Please have a look. May I know what do u mean by adding some rules on my RelativeLayout.Params?